# Positioning Grid-View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter.I have a grid-view with multiple floating-action-buttons. Is there any way I can position my grid-view widget on the y-Axis. I want the grid-view-widget in the middle of the screen.
How can I position layouts in flutter in general ?

Thank you for your help

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          crossAxisSpacing: 15,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                press_1_button();
              },
              child: Text("1"),)
            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: (){
                press_2_button();
              },
            child: Text("2"),)

            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                press_3_button();
              },
              child: Text("3"),)
            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: (){
                press_4_button();
              },
              child: Text("4"),)

            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                press_5_button();
              },
              child: Text("5"),)
            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: (){
                press_6_button();
              },
              child: Text("6"),)

            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                press_7_button();
              },
              child: Text("7"),)
            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: (){
                press_8_button();
              },
              child: Text("8"),)


            ,FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                press_9_button();
              },
              child: Text("9"),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping it with padding

```
Padding(
  padding:const EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0),
  child:GridView(...)
)
```